# Как правильно преобразовать тип

Tags: angular2, typescript

Есть такой код

```
 return this.http.put(url, {product: product}, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
            .map(response => {
                return response.json() as Product;
            })
            .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

product = {
...
unit = {id:null, name:''}
}

Перед отправкой мне нужно сделать так

```
product.unit = product.unit.id
```

Но Typescript  мне естественно так сделать не даст, как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно для чего Вам нужно это сделать. Но очевидно, что так делать не стоит хотя бы потому, что типы как раз для того и придумали, что бы изменить их было проблематично. В данном случае, если я правильно всё понял, вариантов может быть несколько.

- Создать другую переменную с типом, например, `Product2`;
- в интерфейсе Product сделать `unit:any`;
- убрать тип вообще

Comment: сделал пока так  let data: any = Object.assign({}, product);  data.unit     = product.unit.id;

Comment: На стороне сервера апи принимает id, а на клиенте это объект unit  который используется в формах. При получении продукта я получаю объект Unit  внутри

Comment: А Product это интерфейс описанный так `{unit:{id:number;name:'' }`?
 Вы же можете поменять на `{unit:any}` ? И тогда data.unit = product.unit.id;

Comment: типизация на клиенте должна оставаться, только перед отправкой именно в методах put (update) или post но не везде должен предаваться id. Внутри Unit или других подобных объектах могут находится ещё объекты

Comment: Тогда только через промежуточную переменную, как у Вас сейчас